# XML and jQuery - Get XML Code once Modified

Tags: jquery, xml

I am trying to accomplish a quite simple task here: modified a XML string using jQuery and get the modified string back.

I think that before, I could use the .html() function to do this, but I think they got rid of the functionnality with parse XML document.

So, here is the code:

```
var tempXML = "<node1><node2>Content #1</node2></node1>";
var parsedXML = $.parseXML(tempXML);
$(parsedXML).find('node2').text('XXXXXX');
alert($(parsedXML).find('node2').text());  // That works, it will display XXXXXX
```

Now, as I would suspect, the tempXML var is not modified.

So, how do I get the XML code that should read : "XXXXXX"?

Calling $(parsedXML).text(); only return XXXXXX and .html() is not defined for the object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a trick, but here it is:

```
var tempXML = "<node1><node2>Content #1</node2></node1>";
var parsedXML = $.parseXML(tempXML);
$(parsedXML).find('node2').text('XXXXXX');

alert($("<div>").append($(parsedXML).find('node2')).html());​
```

**EDIT**:
Or, here is, I think, more reliable solution:

```
function XMLToString(oXML) {   
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {     
        return oXML.xml;   
    } else {     
        return (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(oXML);   
    } 
}
var tempXML = "<node1><node2>Content #1</node2></node1>";
var parsedXML = $.parseXML(tempXML);
$(parsedXML).find('node2').text('XXXXXX');
alert(XMLToString($(parsedXML).find('node2')[0]));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hJYqe/)

Comment: Yes. But the only thing needed here is to get a string which contains updated XML. Browser will not even display XML tags, but why it should change them?

Comment: @RobW Found some better solution. This one must be more reliable than a trick with <div>